# Possible to copy just the value of an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, clone, dup

I created a 2-D array and tried to copy its value. I tried assignment, dup, and clone.

```
@grid = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3) }
new_grid = @grid.clone
```

Whenever I try to change a value in the new variable, the change is reflected in the original array.

```
new_grid[0][0] = true
@grid # => [[true, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil], [nil, nil, nil]]
```

Is there any way to avoid this linking of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Do deep dup or clone.

```
new_grid = @grid.map(&:dup)
```